# C++ SIGTRAP on allocate array

Tags: c++, matlab-coder

the toolchain I use is Clion MinGW Bundle 
the original code was generated by matlab 
Why SIGTRAP occured when tried to allocate memory?

```cpp
#define CODER_NEW(T, N) new T[N]
void reserve(SZ _n) {
  if (_n > capacity_) {
    T* const new_data{CODER_NEW(T, _n)}; //problem occur
    (void)std::copy(data_, data_ + size_, new_data);
    if (owner_) {
      CODER_DELETE(data_);
    }
    data_ = new_data;
    capacity_ = _n;
    owner_ = true;
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: My guess would be somewhere else in your program corrupted the heap, please show a [mre]

Comment: Does "the original code was generated by matlab" mean that you have been tinkering with generated code?

Comment: @molbdnilo I know why now. Original matlab code can automatic increase capacity. But C++ code doesn't. It writes data without examing. Matlab Coder is buggy. I wish they can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple matlab function

```matlab
function [array] = test(num)
    array = 1:num;
    for i = 1:10 * num
        array(i) = sqrt(double(i)) * num;
    end
end
```

It dynamically increase the size of array. I write this code so that coder cannot guess what size of array will return.
Then I use coder to generate C++ code and use following code to call `test(int num, coder::array<int, 2U> &array)`. Guess what, It crashed.

```
auto array = new coder::array<int, 2U>();
test(100, *array);
delete array;
```

Let's see what happened inside this function.

```
void test(int num, coder::array<int, 2U> &array)
{
  double d;
  long long i;
  int i1;
  // 'test:2' array = 1:num;
  coder::eml_integer_colon_dispatcher(num, array);
  // 'test:3' for i = 1:10 * num
  i = 10LL * num;
  if (i > 2147483647LL) {
    i = 2147483647LL;
  } else if (i < -2147483648LL) {
    i = -2147483648LL;
  }
  i1 = static_cast<int>(i);
  for (int b_i = 0; b_i < i1; b_i++) {
    int i2;
    // 'test:4' array(i) = sqrt(double(i)) * num;
    d = b_i + 1;
    coder::b_sqrt(&d);
    d = rt_roundd_snf(d * static_cast<double>(num));
    if (d < 2.147483648E+9) {
      if (d >= -2.147483648E+9) {
        i2 = static_cast<int>(d);
      } else {
        i2 = MIN_int32_T;
      }
    } else if (d >= 2.147483648E+9) {
      i2 = MAX_int32_T;
    } else {
      i2 = 0;
    }
    array[b_i] = i2;
  }
}
```

First, it allocate memory is size of num. Then it write data to array. The problem here is that it didn't really check index outbound or not.
The real problem here is that array coder produce unlike stl vector is not memory safe. Coder does not write data before check memory outbound.

Comment: Why do you create the array (especially with size 2??) on the heap? That seems like a massive [nonbo](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nonbo). Also the code has so many magic numbers, it's impossible to tell what it does. You might want to  consider using [std::numeric_limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Comment: `Why do you create the array (especially with size 2??` The array has two _dimensions_. `coder::` is not `std::`. `Also the code has so many magic number` yes, it was _autogenerated_ by matlab-coder.

Comment: @infinitezero It's generated by matlab coder. I wish it better too.